# document.getElementById issues with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, api

My code  fetches data from  the backend API

```
for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {}
```

stored object  i want to display in variables and im able to display them accordingly
[image]

everything  is fine until here
but I want to display the description in a popup

```
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup
```

based on this tutorial I have implemented the same

```
     html1 += `  <div class="popup"  onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">${desc}</span>
</div>
            <p > ${desc}</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

  }</script>
         
            `;
```

but when I clicked on it I expected different cards to show different data accordingly but instead, it's just showing the data of  the first card element

[image]

when clicked on the second one only the first card element pops up with only that particular data of that card
I thought the issue could be because of ID so gave dynamic variables as id
but it's of no use When clicked nothing is coming up
not even error
is there any way where we can display dynamic data based upon the card in that popup

Comment: I have a feeling this is related to the for loop and how you are using i. Try changing the i declaration to `let i = 0` instead of `var i = 0` and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique

Use the loop number to make a unique call to the function, and give each span its own ID.

```
     html1 += `  <div class="popup"  onclick="myFunction('${i}')">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup-${i}">${desc}</span>
</div>
            <p > ${desc}</p>
```

and you only need one script block for all of them

```
<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup-"+id);
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

  }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are reusing the same id. In html element IDs have to be unique. You could try to append a sequence number to `id="myPopup"` as you loop, e.g. `id="myPopup1"`, `id="myPopup2"` etc...

Comment: i have mentioned that i have used dynamic varibales based on the data 
but still that couldnt resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using the id property. For that reason the first object works and the others no, Javascript takes the id an use it for the first that find and it discart the others.

Try giving the action by class to every button. Something like this:

```js
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn-toggle')]

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', e => click(e)))

const click = e => e.target.parentElement.children[1].classList.toggle('show')
```

```css
.show {
  color: red;
  display: block!important;
}

.hide{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello from div 1
  <button class="btn-toggle">Toggle</button>
  <div class="hide">Toggle!</div>
</div>
<div>
  Hello from div 2
  <button class="btn-toggle">Toggle</button>
  <div class="hide">Toggle!</div>
</div>
<div>
  Hello from div 3
  <button class="btn-toggle">Toggle</button>
  <div class="hide">Toggle!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not need spread with `querySelectorAll` since it returns a `NodeList` which provides `forEach`. In the browsers it does not, spread is also not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone wrote, `id` is to be unique to work properly.

If you change your css to react to `.popup.show` it would become more simple:

```js
//REM: this = div.popup
function myFunction(div){
  div.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.popup span{
  display: none
}

.popup.show span{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class = 'popup' onclick = 'myFunction(this)'>click<span>clicked</span></div>
```